# Fetch a field from array MongoDB Meteor

Tags: arrays, mongodb, meteor, find

Hi I have the following collection structure:

```html
{
    "_id" : "HZw2ktDPm6EWnGaFt",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-04-16T17:40:59.055Z"),
    "pollName" : "",
    "entryOwner" : "eHPeQPMd94MQFNXmg",
    "question" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Question 1",
            "questionId" : "sdPzbn9SWjE46HtM2"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Question 2",
            "questionId" : "vpMrpbJ2LZKMLEYKe"
        }
    ],
    "sharedWith" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "jjX5EDdqMtcyQwd6h",
            "name" : "person 1",
            "votes" : 0
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "b3Ctr6LFZMd9smd4B",
            "name" : "person 2",
            "votes" : 0
        }
    ],
    "voters" : [ 
        {
            "voterId" : "eHPeQPMd94MQFNXmg",
            "questionId" : "vpMrpbJ2LZKMLEYKe",
            "optionId" : "EKnYKXEFBWnr4hnCP",
            "peopleId" : "b3Ctr6LFZMd9smd4B"
        }, 
        {
            "voterId" : "eHPeQPMd94MQFNXmg",
            "questionId" : "vpMrpbJ2LZKMLEYKe",
            "optionId" : "EKnYKXEFBWnr4hnCP",
            "peopleId" : "jjX5EDdqMtcyQwd6h"
        }, 
        {
            "voterId" : "eHPeQPMd94MQFNXmg",
            "questionId" : "sdPzbn9SWjE46HtM2",
            "optionId" : "rjYLitibXDJjGYKM7",
            "peopleId" : "b3Ctr6LFZMd9smd4B"
        }, 
        {
            "voterId" : "eHPeQPMd94MQFNXmg",
            "questionId" : "Q6JiaGFAi2LRHS7GQ",
            "optionId" : "wFoduKp23cSYJJG9i",
            "peopleId" : "b3Ctr6LFZMd9smd4B"
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to get the value of Voters.peopleId by using these values.

```
        "voterId" : "eHPeQPMd94MQFNXmg",
        "questionId" : "vpMrpbJ2LZKMLEYKe",
        "optionId" : "EKnYKXEFBWnr4hnCP",
```

I tried this and it didnt work it returns the whole document but what i want as a return is just one field:

```html
var getPeopleId = Polls.findOne({ 
        _id:this.props.poll._id}, {"voters": { 
          $elemMatch :{voterId:Meteor.userId(),questionId:selectedQuestionId,optionId:selectedOptionId}}})
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got `$elemMatch` in the projection (2nd param) instead of the query (1st param). You also need to project the result to only include the first match. Try:

```
const poll = Polls.findOne(
  { 
    _id:this.props.poll._id,
    voters: { 
      $elemMatch: {
        voterId: Meteor.userId(),
        questionId: selectedQuestionId,
        optionId: selectedOptionId
    }
  },{
    'voters.$': 1
  });
// guard against missing keys or no results
const peopleId = poll && poll.voters && poll.voters.peopleId;
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but it still returns all fields.